# CentOS permissions, folders, users and groups

Tags: linux, sftp, samba, user-permissions, centos6.5

I am new to Linux and trying to understand permissions for use with remote and local users as well as Samba.  I am running a headless CentOS 6.5 server.  I will try and explain my problem as clear as I can.

I have 2 remote users connecting to a folder using sftp, R_User_1 and R_User_2.   I have 1 local user connecting to the same folder using samba over the local network and one root user.

I have a /home for each user that has folder_1 and folder_2.  Folder_1 is a bind mount of another folder using this line in fstab:

```
/dev/sda2               /media/storage         ext4    defaults        0 1
/media/storage/folder_1  /home/R_User_1/folder_1     none    bind            0 0
```

R_User_1 and R_User_2 both need to have read only access to folder_1 but the local samba user needs to have full access as does root.

Folder_2 is placed in the users home directory and both R_User_1 and R_User_2 need full access to their own folders within the home directory as does root but not the local user.

My question is how do I go about setting up all the permissions for this so that it all works?  I have the users home directories owned by root so that the remote users can not leave their home directory, this is important.

If someone could please help me I would be very grateful.

Cheers

Blinky

Comment: Your setup is mixing a number of things that complicate what you are trying to do. First, if you have chrooted the users to `/home/user_x`, then you are working against what samba is generally designed to do. Primarily, you define a share (a directory somewhere) and then control access by your share definition in /etc/samba/smb.conf (or /etc/smb.conf). You easiest solution is to setup `/home/shared` and make `folder_1` and `folder_2` subdirs of `shared` (or whatever you want to call it). Then make `R_User_1 & R_User_2` members of a unix group (say `rusers`). Allow `rusers` access to `shared`

Comment: Cheers for that, worked a treat once I used a single shared folder.

Comment: Glad it helped! I'll drop it in as the answer so it can help others with the same problem. You can accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is mixing a number of things that complicate what you are trying to do. First, if you have chrooted the users to `/home/user_x`, then you are working against what samba is generally designed to do. Primarily, you define a share (a directory somewhere) and then control access by your share definition in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` (or /etc/smb.conf). Your easiest solution is to setup `/home/shared` and make `folder_1` and `folder_2` subdirs of shared (or whatever you want to call it). Then make `R_User_1` & `R_User_2` members of a unix group (say `rusers`). Allow `rusers` access to `shared`.